# Python print unicode strings in arrays as characters, not code points

Tags: python, unicode

If I've got a dictionary of the form:

`a = {u"foo": u"ბარ"}`

and I write

`>>> print a[u"foo"]`

I get

`ბარ`

as expected. But if I write

`>>> print a`

I get

`{u'foo': u'\u10d1\u10d0\u10e0'}`, but I would prefer the characters themselves to be printed.

All the data will ultimately get dumped into a database anyway, so it's not critical to solve this problem, but for debugging it would be nice if I could get readable output when I print the entire dictionary. Is there any way to do this?

For those who are curious, the script is Georgian, and yes, it says "bar".

Answer (score 74, accepted):

This works in my terminal:

```
print repr(a).decode("unicode-escape")
```

Comment: i'm getting wrongs strings, for example "indeterminaÃ§Ã£o" instead "indeterminação".

Comment: @ademar111190 : Looks like it's trying to use UTF-8, but your terminal is displaying it in a single-byte encoding, like cp1252. Try `print repr(a).decode('unicode-escape').encode('latin-1')`.

Answer (score 0):

Thomas answer is absolutely correct. I just want to add this line for everyone who wants  a more readable output:

```
print json.dumps(a, indent=4, default=str).decode('unicode-escape')
```