# print python dictionary with utf8 values

Tags: python, dictionary, utf-8

I have dictionary with utf8 string values. I need to print it without any **\xd1** , **\u0441** or **u**'string' symbols.

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

a = u'lang=русский'

# prints: lang=русский
print(a)

mydict = {}
mydict['string'] = a
mydict2 = repr(mydict).decode("unicode-escape")

# prints: {'string': u'lang=русский'}
print mydict2
```

expected

```
{'string': 'lang=русский'}
```

Is it possible without parsing the dictionary?
This question is related with [Python print unicode strings in arrays as characters, not code points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5648573/python-print-unicode-strings-in-arrays-as-characters-not-code-points) , but I need to get rid from that annoying **u**

Comment: Why do you need to produce that output? Python containers use `repr()` for the contents, and that means that Unicode values are shown with non-ASCII and non-printable characters are shown with escape sequences and with the `u` prefix. Don't use `repr()` if you don't want that display but loop over the contents yourself..

Comment: Is switching to Python 3 an option? Where all strings are Unicode strings and the `u` prefix isn't needed anymore?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't see a reasonable use case for this, but if you want a custom representation of a dictionary (or better said, a custom representation of a unicode object within a dictionary), you can roll it yourself:

```
def repr_dict(d):
    return '{%s}' % ',\n'.join("'%s': '%s'" % pair for pair in d.iteritems())
```

and then

```
print repr_dict({u'string': u'lang=русский'})
```