# Yet another JSON/encoding error in Python

Tags: python, json, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I've read [Unicode HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html) several times, and solve similar problems many times, still not understanding how. Anyone can help me on how to properly print this loaded json ?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# coding: utf8

import json

s = u'["poêle", "mangé"]'
print s
l = json.loads(s)
print l
```

I've tried every combination of enconding/encode/decode/unicode I could though of... and yet the second print is ugly :

```
$ python test.py
["poêle", "mangé"]
[u'po\xeale', u'mang\xe9']
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To pretty print your list try the following taken from [this so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5648573/python-print-unicode-strings-in-arrays-as-characters-not-code-points)

`print repr(l).decode('unicode-escape')`

> Also, when you print a list, it prints the `repr` of the elements.

`print l[0], l[1]` is different from `print l`, so you can always iterate over the elements and print them. `print l[0], l[1]` will also print the characters properly.

This should help you understand the differences

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __repr__(self):
        return "<repr: MyClass>"

    def __str__(self):
        return "<str: MyClass>"

l = [ MyClass(), MyClass(), MyClass() ]
print l
print l[0], l[1], l[2]
```

> output

```
[<repr: MyClass>, <repr: MyClass>, <repr: MyClass>]
<str: MyClass> <str: MyClass> <str: MyClass>
```